# Sentence Completion: "The question of ___ in photography has lately become nontrivial..."

Tags: complex-sentences

> The question of (i) **_ in photography has lately become nontrivial.
>   Prices for vintage prints (those made by a photographer soon after he
>   or she made the negative) so drastically (ii)_____ in the 1990s that
>   one of these photographs might fetch a hundred times as much as a
>   nonvintage print of the same image. It was perhaps only a matter of
>   time before someone took advantage of the (iii)_** to peddle newly
>   created "vintage" prints for profit.

---

I was able to figure out the first and the second blanks (the second being obvious). But the third blank has perplexed me.

Here are the options:
(i) forgery; influence; style
(ii) ballooned; weakened; varied
(iii) discrepancy; ambiguity; duplicity

**EDIT**

Though 'ballooned' seemed to be the most appropriate choice for the
second blank, for it is said that the 'vintage' print might fetch a
"hundred times", the choices for the first and third blank seem
confusing.

I was confused that *duplicity* OR *discrepancy* can both go (third blank)
with *forgery* (first blank).

This was the actual doubt. And I'm thankful to Amir Sabanovic for
addressing exactly that.

What I do not appreciate is that without even extending a modicum of
support, a few senior community members simply voted to close the
question as being off-topic citing the reason as 'PROOF READING'. I am
baffled by the fact that unless I would have returned to analyze the
question, would have never known that the question was on hold and
closed. I think that a simple comment suggesting the improvement(s)
required would have been much better than 'simply' marking the
question as off-topic. After all, what exactly is 'off-topic' in the
question must be explicitly mentioned. Also, I have gone through the
 help centre and shared my findings in the comments below.

But I'll leave it to the veterans for a holistic explanation.

Comment: The correct answer, by the way, is _differential deblenification_.

Comment: To those who have voted to close this question: I have gone through the 'help centre' and found this as the first point-

"Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:

Word choice and usage"

And did not find any of the points that makes this question incongruous with the site. 

Hence, please suggest specific additions/modifications that need to be made to the post to make it appropriate.

Looking forward to hearing from all those who voted!

Comment: I think if you had offered your choice and explained *why* you thought it might have been unsuitable, then the question would not have been closed. However, the site does receive a lot of requests of  "please fill in the blanks" questions, with no previous research, and accompanied by an almost lackadaisical attitude. Your post was better than most because you provided the answers to two of the blanks, BUT you didn't share any of your research. .

Comment: EL&U is a tough crowd to please, (I know!) but you should be aiming to whet their curiosity and interest, not complete your homework or provide the answers to English test questions. Furthermore, consider that this type of question has a very limited appeal to learners and enthusiasts alike.

Comment: I've just realized that you never actually *said* what the answers were to blanks No1 and 2! :)

Comment: Yes, I explained that in the edit even though nobody pointed it out explicitly (as metioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) *forgery* (ii) *ballooned* (iii) *discrepancy*

*Discrepancy* refers to the difference in pricing between vintage and non-vintage prints.

Comment: But 'forgery' can also refer to 'duplicity'.

Though I agree with your explanation of 'discrepancy' referring to 'difference in pricing'. I related it to a 'dispute' between the fraudulent and original prints. 

Actually, it was not clear to me what 'forgery' has to do with the context at all, initially! But selected it because no other option seemed a better fit. What was your interpretation to choose 'forgery'?

Comment: The fact that they began selling `"vintage"` prints led me to believe that — inspired by the newly present discrepancy — they had found a way to successfully *forge* vintage prints and trick people into thinking that they really are vintage.

Comment: Ah! I now get it. My interpretation was flawed in that, I believed that 'vintage' prints - as explained in those braces - meant that a photograph that could be produced immediately. But the story is a little different than that. It is actually talking about the 'original' prints instead of a newly printed replica which are actually the forged prints the author is talking about. 

THanks for the help!

Comment: @Vaibhav as far as I can tell from your post before the edit, you did not mention anything about your interpretation, had you done so it would have been easier to see why you were asking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Agree! Actually, as mentioned in my comment, I never recognized the interpretation of 'vintage' as flawed until a retrospection corollary to Amir's explanation. Having said that, will certainly keep your suggestions in mind. And yes, this is what I appreciate. Atleast now I know where I need(ed) to improve.. :)